# Unity C# AES - Can't send IV

Tags: c#, aes

I am having a problem with my code and cannot figure out the problem.

With fullMsg set to false it works.

If I change fullMsg to true it no longer works even if I set it back to false.

I have no idea what is going on as the byte[] array remains the same in all the cases.

[image]

```
private void sendIndividualMsg(string msg){

    //Debug.Log (msg);

    byte[] toSend = PackageMsg (msg);
    byte[] decoded = UnPackageMsg (toSend);


    Debug.Log(  System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(decoded) );
}

private byte[] UnPackageMsg(byte[] msg){

    var toDecrypt = msg;

    if (fullMsg) {

        toDecrypt = new byte[msg.Length - 16];  
        var decryptIV = new byte[16];           

        System.Buffer.BlockCopy (msg, 0, decryptIV, 0, 16);
        System.Buffer.BlockCopy (msg, 16, toDecrypt, 0, (msg.Length - 16));

        //myAes.IV = decryptIV;
    }

    PrintByteArray (toDecrypt, "ToDecrypt");



    byte[] plaintext;

    // Create the streams used for decryption.
    {

        ICryptoTransform decryptor = myAes.CreateDecryptor (myAes.Key, myAes.IV);
        MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream ();
        CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream (msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);

        csDecrypt.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
        csDecrypt.FlushFinalBlock();  
        csDecrypt.Close();


        plaintext = msDecrypt.ToArray();


        msDecrypt.Close ();
        decryptor.Dispose();

    }
    if (plaintext.Length > 16) {


        byte[] hash = new byte[16];     
        byte[] hashCalc = new byte[16];     

        byte[] payload = new byte[plaintext.Length - 16 ];      

        System.Buffer.BlockCopy (plaintext, 0, hash, 0, 16);
        System.Buffer.BlockCopy (plaintext, 16, payload, 0, plaintext.Length - 16);

        hashCalc = md5.ComputeHash(payload);

        if(ByteArrayCompare(hash, hashCalc)){
            return payload;
        }else{
            return new byte[0];
        }



    } else {
        return new byte[0];
    }


}

private byte[] PackageMsg(string msg){

    System.Text.ASCIIEncoding ue = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();

    byte[] bytes = ue.GetBytes(msg);






    byte[] hashBytes = md5.ComputeHash(bytes);

    byte[] toEncrypt = new byte[bytes.Length + hashBytes.Length];       
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(hashBytes, 0, toEncrypt, 0, hashBytes.Length);
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, 0, toEncrypt, hashBytes.Length, bytes.Length);

    //myAes.GenerateIV();

    byte[] encrypted;


    {
        ICryptoTransform encryptor = myAes.CreateEncryptor (myAes.Key, myAes.IV);
        MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream ();
        CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream (msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);


        csEncrypt.Write(toEncrypt, 0, toEncrypt.Length);
        csEncrypt.FlushFinalBlock();  
        csEncrypt.Close();

        encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();

        msEncrypt.Close ();
        encryptor.Dispose();

    }

    PrintByteArray (encrypted, "Encrypted");

    //SessionBytes + IV + ENCRYPTED( hash + msg)


    byte[] finalMsg = new byte[myAes.IV.Length + encrypted.Length ];

    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(myAes.IV, 0, finalMsg, 0 , myAes.IV.Length);
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(encrypted, 0, finalMsg, myAes.IV.Length , encrypted.Length);

    if (!fullMsg) {
        finalMsg = encrypted;
    }

    return finalMsg;
```

### }

(I want to send the IV through each message, but until I get this working their is no point.)

Basic explanation of the algorithm for encrypting:

If fullMsg is set the encryption is [session][iv][encryptedmsg]

If fullMsg is not set the encryption is [encryptedmsg]

For Decryption the first part of the code is too extract just the encryptedmsg part.

As show by the screenshot of the logs, in both modes the bytes are the same.

--

Comment: I don't understand your key and IV management. Are they always the same? Why are you sending the IV with the message then?

Comment: Can you remove the "SessionBytes"? They don't seem to be defined and appear only on encrypting. You need to simplify this code so that people can understand it.

Comment: How can it be true that the byte array is not affected when changing fullMsg? According to the code it clearly should be. Also, what does "not work" mean?

Comment: I am sending the IVs through so that I can change it (once I get this code working). It is not currently working due to getting a 'Invalid Input Block Size' error.  What is sent is [IV][Encrypted] Or [Encrypted]. The printbytearray in UnPackageMsg is giving me the same bytes in both modes.

Comment: You're not using `toDecrypt` in `UnPackageMsg` after setting. Instead you keep using `msg`. You should change that, but I'm still not sure what you're trying to do. This is not the correct way of implementing a streaming API.

Comment: I am encrypting it so I can send over UDP. This is just the encryption level of the network. What do you think needs to be done for the streaming API?